# XmlTextWriter Allows Illegal Unicode Characters

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextwriter

`XmlTextWriter` allows `0x15` and `0x1A`.  Does anyone know how to get around this?  If I serialize a string of XML containing the mentioned illegal characters `XmlTextWriter` allows this with no exceptions.  Does anyone have a work around for this?

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are these illegal? `0x15` is just `21` decimal, what's special about that?

Comment: Before now I've just done a blind replace for any "banned" characters - but obviously that loses data. Unfortunately in XML 1.0 there isn't really a nice workaround for it - the characters are still invalid even when specified as an entity :(

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Only a few characters in the range U+0000 to U+001F are legal :( See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets

Comment: @JonSkeet: cheers, that clarifies some things. Character sets.. *shudder*

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments, we ending up solving the issue using XmlConvert.IsXmlChar